# How can I stagger http requests?

Tags: node.js

I have an `async` function in order to make a series of http requests which I would like to be buffered by 1 second in between requests.  I am utilizing `async.forEachof` and putting the iterator callback function in the callback of the `http.request` method.  Code is below

```
const async = require('async');
const http = require('http');
let https = require('https');
let fs = require('fs');

async.forEachOf([0,1,2,3], function(tag, index, cb){
  let options = {
    host: 'www.google.com',
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
  };

  var waitTill = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000);
  while(waitTill > new Date()){}

  console.log('POST');

  https.request(options, function(res){
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    cb()
  }).end(JSON.stringify({}));
});
```

I would expect output to be

`POST`

`200`

`POST`

`200`

etc...

Instead I get

`POST`

`POST`

`POST`

`POST`

`200`

`200`

`200`

`200`

So all the requests are firing at the same time, and the iteration is not waiting for the previous function to complete.  I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is because we are passing callback function is http.request method.
Which will be executed by node's event loop as and when necessary resources are free and we get response over the network.(Basically async network call.)

Can u check async waterfall api through which u can execute api calls sequentially as desired.

Next option is use nodes native async await apis.

Or you can try using [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) package and use generators with promises.